# Building C# classes from JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio

When consuming a new API you have to generate the c# classes to represent the JSON schema. Doing it manually is awful. I love [jsonutils.com](https://jsonutils.com/) but is there a Visual Studio ability or add on for this I am not finding?

Comment: [You can paste as classes in VS since 2015](http://dailydotnettips.com/2017/11/09/did-you-know-you-can-automatically-create-classes-from-json-or-xml-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Downvoters, did *you* know about this? I wonder, when did you find out that you can use a simple Paste to generate classes? Would you have *remembered* this command exists if it wasn't for maccettura's comment and the duplicate?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing the reason was because the question has already been answered which indicates a lack of research on OP's part. Not anything to do with not knowing the answer, but not bothering to research before creating the question.

Comment: @Panagiotis I didn't downvote but the first SO Google result (if you search for OP's question title) answers the question wirh exactly what OP is looking for. The lack of research is something I would downvote for.

Comment: @itsme86 did you *remember* the feature was there? I didn't. It's probably the 3rd time I rediscovered it. If you don't know there's a thing called `Paste JSON as Classes` you won't be able to find it

Comment: Answering your question but for myself: I'm aware the feature is there, but I do not have plans to start using it. I prefer to write JSON models myself.